# How many string objects are getting created for this program?

Tags: java, string

I'm getting same hashcodes for these two objects.

**CASE 1**

```
String s=new String("ll");
String s1=new String(s);
```

but for case 2 I am getting different hash codes

**CASE 2**

```
String s=new String("ll");
String s1=new String("ll");
```

So in case 1 are  two different objects geting created or only one ?

Comment: Case 2 should *not* have two different hash codes. You must have made a mistake.

Comment: String is a special immutable class in java, please read: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html  that should clear it up.  If you really want to see what it going on, debug yoru code and see instance id attached to each object.

Answer (score 2):

The 'new' keyword always creates a new object.
Therefore, in both cases 1 and 2, the references s and s1 denote separate objects.

Given the hashcode is based on value, in both cases, the **same** hashcode is getting generated for each of s and s1.

Code as below:

```
  // CASE 1
  String s=new String("ll");
  String s1=new String(s);
  System.out.println(s.hashCode());       //prints 3456
  System.out.println(s1.hashCode());      //prints 3456

  // CASE 2
  String ss=new String("ll");
  String ss1=new String("ll");
  System.out.println(ss.hashCode());       //prints 3456
  System.out.println(ss1.hashCode());      //also prints 3456
```